# Bad synchronous description - simple vhdl program

Tags: vhdl

I trying to make a simple VHDL program which consist of incrementing a std_logic_vector by one every time  button A is pressed. When button B is pressed the value should be reset.

My idea was to do it like this

```
entity simple is
    Port ( A : in std_logic;
           B : in std_logic;
           CLK : in std_logic;
           debug : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0));
end simple;

architecture Behavioral of simple is
    signal state: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
begin

   increment: process(state, A, B)
    begin
        if (B'event and B = '1') then 
            state <= "00000000";
        end if;
        if (A'event andA = '1') then 
            state <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(state)+1);
         end if;
    end process;


    led_debug: process(CLK)
    begin
        debug <= state;
    end process;    

end Behavioral;
```

The problem is though i am getting a error - Bad synchronous description, which i cannot understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized It was checking at 2 rising edges within the same process, making the system sensitive to 2 clock, which was giving it a bad synchronous.

Comment: The B button can be used as an asynchronous reset.

Answer (score 1):

I reworked your code into a full synchronous description:

1. Synchronous designs need a clock-signal, but a button signal is no clock. So every process is triggered on a positive edge of `Clk`.
2. I changed the type of state to spare some type conversions.
3. If `A` is active, then the counter is reset to zero.
4. Otherwise if `B` is active, it increments.
5. I assume your `led_debug` process should be clocked to, so I added a rising_edge condition.

This solution does not solve the following problem, if `A` and `B` are wires from a external button:

- External signals need to be synchronized with at least 2 FFs, to avoid metastability problems.
- External buttons mostly need a debounce circuit, because button inputs bounce. There are also electrical or mechanical solutions possible to solve the problem. Have a look into your board descriptions and board schematics.
- In most cases you want to count button presses. Your current solution measures how long you have pressed the button (this needs also a bigger counter). This problem can be solved by an edge detection circuit.

Here is the rewritten code:

```
entity simple is
  Port (
    CLK : in std_logic;
    A : in std_logic;
    B : in std_logic;
    debug : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)
  );
end entity;

architecture rtl of simple is
  signal state : unsigned(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin
  increment : process(Clk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(Clk) then
      if (B = '1') then 
        state <= "00000000";
      elsif (A = '1') then 
        state <= state + 1;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  led_debug : process(CLK)
  begin
    if rising_edge(Clk) then
      debug <= std_logic_vector(state);
    end if;
  end process;    
end architecture;
```

Comment: Adding another register for `debug` isn't quite necessary.

Comment: I translated his code. And yes in some cases you'll need 1 to 3 register stages for a debug port to an internal state. Of cause the debug circuit is more then a LED ...